# Help installing Broadcom 43142 with no internet access

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm new to linux, and have a copy (thanks, freegeek!) Of 12.04.5 for AMD 64-bit desktop I'd like to install on my new hard drive, but I cannot seem to install the drivers for my wireless card.  Lspci -nn -d 14e4 returns 14e4:4365 (rev 01). I have a dvd copy of bcmwl-kernel-source, and a usb copy of the driver from the manufacturer's website, which I've copied to my desktop. I've tried apt-get a couple of times, but aside from that, it's a clean install. I do NOT have a hardwired connection I can access, however, and until I get the wireless adaptor working, no internet access on my computer (unless one of you can tell me how to tether my laptop to either my blackberry or my ps4)  Any help you can lend me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the wireless work when running the live cd?

Comment: Have you tried to install the "bcmwl-kernel-source" from your DVD? How did you do that?

Comment: I personally tested this specific model in http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395 but this was with 14.04 and 15.04.

Comment: Sorry for poor formatting on this thread, I'm writing on my phone, and thanks for your help. Wireless does not work from the live cd, nor from the usb. @ P.-H, I don't know how to install from the dvd. I tried the installer, but it hung (3 times) when I ticked the "install propriatary drivers" box, so I tried without it.  @ luis, I didn't see your thread, but I'll look into it now. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: @Luis, that's in fact the thread I am trying to follow, but I'm trying to install the driver from a local source. Apt-get doesn't seem to find it.

Comment: You might be able to double click on the file to install it if it is a deb file

Answer (score 0):

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 for testing I noticed the package names were different. They were merged on future releases. So for your case I would recommend doing the following and please let us know how it went:

```
   sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
  sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Now reboot. If that one does not work then remove it and install one of the following:

```
  sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

Or

```
  sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot and let us know how it went. But just in case I highly recommend updating to 14.04 or even 15.04 when it comes out. The broadcom drivers are much better there and even have better range and speed.

Comment: Unfortunately, apt-get only returns a bunch of "could not resolve xxxx.ubuntu.com" messages. :(

Comment: Change repository source by going to Dash, typing Software & Updates and changing it there.

Comment: Ok, after a couple hours in an internet cafe, i've finally got a working internet connection(and 14.10)! but only if I boot from my usb.  I installed it on my HDD, but when i go to software and updates>Additional drivers, and attempt to select the bcmwl-kernel-source package, hit apply changes...a progress bar appears, disappears, then the "do not use this device" radio button is on again.  I've reinstalled twice, to no avail. :(

Comment: Can you do it via the terminal, like sudo apt-get install  bcmwl-kernel-source to see what the error is.

Comment: Sadly, the error is that it can't resolve the host ca.archive.ubuntu.com when I boot from Hard disc.  it works perfectly from the usb install, so I've got a copy of what I need locally...is there any way to point apt-get at my usb drive, instead of the internet that it can't connect to?